# Issue with spannable and Ellipsize in TextView

Tags: android, textview, ellipsis, spannable

I have a news feed in my app.  In a feed item I have a text view which may have url links and hashtags.  I need the both the urls and the hashtags to be clickable which is implemented.

```
 protected void setTextClickable(TextView txtView) {

       L.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "SET TEXT CLICKABLE ENTERED" + "LINES: " +String.valueOf(mTextViewLines));

        String text = txtView.getText().toString();
        ExpandableTextViewClickableSpan clickSpan = null;
        ExpandableTextViewClickableSpan clickableSpan = null;

        final SpannableString hashTagInText = new SpannableString(text);
        String regexURL = "\\(?\\b((http|https)://|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&amp;@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&amp;@#/%=~_()|]";
        String regexHashTag = "#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)";
        Matcher matcherURL = Pattern.compile(regexURL).matcher(hashTagInText);
        Matcher matcherHashTag = Pattern.compile(regexHashTag).matcher(hashTagInText);
        int color = view.getResources().getColor(R.color.tinted_green_colour);

        while (matcherURL.find()) {
            clickSpan = new ExpandableTextViewClickableSpan(currentFragment, false, color, hashTagInText,
                    matcherURL.start(), matcherURL.end(),  MenuUtils.sURL_LINKID);
            hashTagInText.setSpan(clickSpan, matcherURL.start(), matcherURL.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        while (matcherHashTag.find()) {
            clickableSpan   = new ExpandableTextViewClickableSpan(currentFragment, false, color, hashTagInText,
                    matcherHashTag.start(), matcherHashTag.end(), MenuUtils.sHASHTAG_LINKID);
            hashTagInText.setSpan(clickableSpan, matcherHashTag.start(), matcherHashTag.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
}
```

However, there is also the requirement that if the message is longer than 4 lines then I ellipsis and show a view more/less option.

Since introducing the method to colour and set clickable the urls and hashtags (which works with spannables which then renders the ellipsis ineffective).

So now my ellipsis doesn't work.  I came across this [Spannable Ellipsis Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691511/textview-using-spannable-ellipsize-doesnt-work) on SO.  However this requires a line count which I can't get unless it's done in a global layout listener.

Which I have done and successfully get the line count.  The problem is however that the bind data method is called in which the spannable is applied and layout populated (where I want to apply my own ellipsis method) before the `onGlobalLayout` method is called, which then leaves me with 0 line count.

Is there a simple way to combine both ellipsis and spannable?  Any help is appreciated.