# Ellipsis Not Appearing in Textview

Tags: xml, kotlin, textview

**EDIT**: The issue was with '**LinkMovementMethod**', and removing it solved the problem, but now the clickability of the spannable is gone. Does anyone have a solution for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Below, in the 'confessionsScreenConfession' TextView, I want to display three dots if the text exceeds 2 lines, but even though I've set maxLines=2 and ellipsize=end, three dots are not appearing when the text exceeds 2 lines. Where am I making a mistake?

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:paddingVertical="8dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/confessionsScreenProfileImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/empty_profile_photo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/confessionsScreenProfileImage"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/confessionsScreenUsername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:text="username"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/middle_dot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:text="·"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/confessionsScreenTimestamp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alpha="0.75"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="timestamp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/confessionsScreenConfession"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/icon_and_favorite_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_answer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_answer" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.5" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_favorite"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progress_bar_favorite"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:indeterminateTint="@color/black"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ic_favorite"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ic_favorite"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ic_favorite"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ic_favorite" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/more_action_button"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:contentDescription="Açılır Menü"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ellipses" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

By the way, I'm setting a spannable value to the text of this TextView, and I thought the issue might be related to that, so I also set the text as plain text (exceeding 2 lines), but the three dots still didn't appear. I believe the issue is with the XML, and I've tried several attempts but couldn't succeed.

```
    val toUserName = "@${confess.username} "
val spannable = SpannableString("$toUserName${confess.text}")

val usernameColor = ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.confessmered)
val usernameStart = 0
val usernameEnd = toUserName.length

spannable.setSpan(
    object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            val userNameClickedUser = confessList[adapterPosition]

            if (currentUserUid != userNameClickedUser.userId) {
                onUserNameClick(
                    userNameClickedUser.userId,
                    userNameClickedUser.email,
                    userNameClickedUser.username
                )
            }
        }

        override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
            ds.color = usernameColor
            ds.isUnderlineText = false
        }
    },
    usernameStart,
    usernameEnd,
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
)

spannable.setSpan(
    StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
    usernameStart,
    usernameEnd,
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
)

binding.confessionsScreenUsername.text = confess.fromUserUsername
binding.confessionsScreenConfession.text = spannable
binding.confessionsScreenConfession.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
binding.confessionsScreenConfession.highlightColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

Comment: Is this the answer that you looking for? [TextView using Spannable - ellipsize doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30446822/16076805)